USB device mode setup packet preparing
I am trying to understand USB device related code provided by STMicroelectronics -eg on this link.
What I cannot find in code is where EP0 OUT XFRSIZ value is loaded (with setup packet length ie 24) after finishing previous Setup request (eg SetAddress) and as a preparation step for receiving new Setup packet ?
For example it is done in function USB_EP0_OutStart after USB Reset, but later on when time comes to prepare EP0 for new setup packet, this is done only in the case of using DMA mode (in function - PCD_EP_OutSetupPacket_int).
However the initialization sets non DMA as working mode.
Regards
